# Auth header not being set with Axios PUT request

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to set the header in an Axios `PUT` request with my Auth token, but when I view the call on the server (running my UI app from localhost) the header is null. I've used this same pattern with Axios and `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE` calls without issue. Is there anything different with respect to a `PUT` call and the header?

Below is the code:

```
return axios.put(BASE_URI + '/submissions/' + submissionId + '/submit',
    {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add headers in POST or PUT, you need a third argument which will contain `headers` keys

> axios.put(url, data, config)

```
return axios.put(BASE_URI + '/submissions/' + submissionId + '/submit',
   {}, // post/put body
   {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken,
   }
})
```